# Remove from vector to add another element

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a method to check if a vector (that must have no more than n elements) is full and that remove the first element to add another one?

Comment: `if (v.size() >= n) v.erase(v.begin());` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Use a std::deque instead or search for "c++ circular buffer"

Comment: @DieterLücking Does `std::deque` support a size limit?

Comment: Do you want to replace the first element? Where does the new element go?

Comment: @NeilKirk We've been implementing a fixed sized queue based on a `std::array` ringbuffer, and we came up with a load more behavioral policies to configure (exceptions/return values, etc.). It's a really broad topic.

Comment: @NeilKirk Well, we did so for cases, where really you want to have _queue_ semantics. But _"add another one?"_ could be understood as _`std::vector::push_back()`_ should be used. I'm afraid the question is just unclear, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a `std::deque`. Deque supports popping and pushing from both directions i.e. front and back. (As already mentioned in the comments)

```
void my_push(std::deque<int>& sample, int element)
{
    if(sample.size() >= MAX_SIZE)
    {
        sample.pop_front(); // pop off the front element.
        sample.push_front(element);
    }
    else {
         // do whatever you want to...
    }
}
```